# Given a binary, is it possible to find the make recipe that generated it?

Tags: gcc, makefile, compilation, shared-libraries

Looking for something kind of like rpm -q that tells you where a package came from, but instead of package info, I want compiler information.

I've looked in man page for make, but i don't see/understand-if-there-are any reverse options. https://linux.die.net/man/1/make

Is it possible to have gcc compiler tell you? The reason I'm asking is because I've a binary that was built agains some *.so and I know i can use ldd on the binary to find those shared objects, but it would be nice to see the compile command. I don't understand a lot about .so, so any descriptive /background information would be useful.

Comment: The short answer is "no".  You can find the list of shared objects that are required by a binary because the binary contains that list.  You can find information about where a package came from because the RPM facility stashes away a database of what packages are installed.  There is nothing that will automatically put the recipe (or even just the compile line) used to link a program (much less all the compile lines used to compile individual objects of that program) into the program itself so it can be retrieved later.